# Setting the value for 'android: layout_below' property to a resource id from a different layout xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

I have a blueprint which looks as thus: [image: content_main_sportsbook.xml]

I have the tablayout widget specified in xml like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/tabBg"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/grey"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

I set it up with a ViewPager scrolling to swipe views for each tab. Now in one of the views - Tab 3, I need to arrange my components below the @id/tabLayout

This is the content of tab3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="second"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/secondtext"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="third"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Both the second and third textviews are displayed behind the tabLayout, they are covered/hidden by the tabLayout. How do i specify the textviews to display right under the tabLayout so the text is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RelativeLayout, like any other layout, is only responsible for laying out it's direct children. Therefore, the `android:layout_below` and similar attributes, can only work for two views within the same RelativeLayout parent.

In this case, you'd have to add it to the ViewPager. Then the TextViews can be just at the top of their container, as that is now below the TabBar.

If this is no good for your other tabs. You can do one of:
- Have the TabBar be a fixed height and set that as margin to the textviews
- Query the height of TabBar at runtime an apply it as padding or margin in tab3.

Comment: This is the clarification i was looking for. I'll go with the second suggestion: Get the height of the tabLayout at runtime and apply it as a top-margin to the content of tab3, or even maybe the whole relative layout of tab 3.

Answer (score 0):

Define an id to RelativeLayout in tab3.xml and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use linear layout with vertical orientation .. It will work :)

Comment: in both tab3.xml and content_main_sportsbook.xml?

Comment: Use linear layout in both